# Iterating over dictionary keys with a function

Tags: python, list, function, loops, dictionary

Creating a dictionary from the play Macbeth

(credit to @Ajax1234)

```py
import requests, re
from collections import defaultdict
r = requests.get('https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2264/pg2264.txt').text
d, l, keywords = defaultdict(list), None, ['Enter', 'Exit', 'Flourish', 'Thunder']
for i, a in filter(lambda x:x[-1], enumerate(re.split('[\n\r]+', r[r.index('Actus Primus. Scoena Prima.')+27:]))):
   if not re.findall('|'.join(keywords), a):
        if (n:=re.findall('^\s+[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*[a-z]+\.(?=\s\w+)|^[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*[a-z\.]+\.(?=\s\w+)', a)):
            d[(l:=re.sub('^\s+|\.$', '', n[0]).lower())].append((i, a[len(n[0])+1:].lower()))
        elif l:
            d[l].append((i, a.lower()))
```

keys: names

```py
['all', 'king', 'mal', 'cap', 'lenox', 'rosse', 'macb', 'banquo', 'mac', 'banq', 'ang', 'lady', 'mess', 'la', 'fleance', 'porter', 'macd', 'port', 'exeunt', 'ban', 'donal', 'malc', 'don', 'ross', 'seruant', 'murth', 'lords', 'mur', 'len', 'hec', 'lord', 'appar', 'musicke', 'wife', 'son', 'mes', 'doct', 'ro', 'gent', 'lad', 'ment', 'cath', 'ser', 'sey', 'seyw', 'sold', 'syw', 'y.sey']
```

Values: lines spoken

Example of first ten lines from 'macb' from keys:

```py
[(137, 'so foule and faire a day i haue not seene'), (170, 'stay you imperfect speakers, tell me more:'), (171, 'by sinells death, i know i am thane of glamis,'), (172, 'but how, of cawdor? the thane of cawdor liues'), (173, 'a prosperous gentleman: and to be king,'), (174, 'stands not within the prospect of beleefe,'), (175, 'no more then to be cawdor. say from whence'), (176, 'you owe this strange intelligence, or why'), (177, 'vpon this blasted heath you stop our way'), (178, 'with such prophetique greeting?')]
```

#### Getting The top 5 lines from a character

(Credit to @Ajax1234)

```py
from collections import Counter
def common_words(character, filter_stop = False, stop_words = []):
   if filter_stop:
      stop_words = set(filter(None, requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sebleier/554280/raw/7e0e4a1ce04c2bb7bd41089c9821dbcf6d0c786c/NLTK's%2520list%2520of%2520english%2520stopwords").text.split('\n')))
   w = [i for _, b in d['macb'] for i in re.sub('[\:\.\?]+', '', b).split() if i.lower() not in stop_words]
   return Counter(w).most_common(5)

print(common_words('macb', filter_stop = True))
```

output

```
['all', 'king', 'mal', 'cap', 'lenox', 'rosse', 'macb', 'banquo', 'mac', 'banq', 'ang', 'lady', 'mess', 'la', 'fleance', 'porter', 'macd', 'port', 'exeunt', 'ban', 'donal', 'malc', 'don', 'ross', 'seruant', 'murth', 'lords', 'mur', 'len', 'hec', 'lord', 'appar', 'musicke', 'wife', 'son', 'mes', 'doct', 'ro', 'gent', 'lad', 'ment', 'cath', 'ser', 'sey', 'seyw', 'sold', 'syw', 'y.sey']
[(137, 'so foule and faire a day i haue not seene'), (170, 'stay you imperfect speakers, tell me more:'), (171, 'by sinells death, i know i am thane of glamis,'), (172, 'but how, of cawdor? the thane of cawdor liues'), (173, 'a prosperous gentleman: and to be king,'), (174, 'stands not within the prospect of beleefe,'), (175, 'no more then to be cawdor. say from whence'), (176, 'you owe this strange intelligence, or why'), (177, 'vpon this blasted heath you stop our way'), (178, 'with such prophetique greeting?')]
```

#### Here's the issue I'm having:

Iterate over the keys (names), passing each name into the `common_words` function above:

```
def final_common(data):
    group_common = []
    
    for name in data:
        common = common_words(name)
        if common not in group_common:
            group_common.append(common)
        else:
            pass
    return group_common
        
print(final_common(names))
```

**this only outputs the top five words of the first name in the list. I need all the names and their top five words**

example

```
'macb', [('haue', 39), ('thou', 34), ('thy', 23), ('shall', 21), ('thee', 20)]
'king', [('hello, 22), ('free', 21), ('actually', 18), ('thee', 16), ('thou', 12)
etc...
```

Comment: what is "d" in d['macb'] ?

Comment: @Vizzyy I've added the code describing d['macb'] above.

Comment: What's the point of `filter()`? It's filtering out empty lines, but your `re.split` won't return empty lines.

Comment: Wouldn't pandas be a good tool for this?

Comment: That part of the code is beyond my skill level I'm afraid, @Barmar. I'm stuck at the looping dictionary keys into **final_common** to return the names of the characters and their top five uttered words.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How did you write it if it's beyond your skill level?

Comment: `group_common` should be a dictionary, not a list. The keys are names, values are the character's top 5 words.

Comment: @Barmar okay, thanks a lot

Comment: is this will be your result for the first 5 keys in `d` `[{'all': [('double,', 6),
   ('cauldron', 4),
   ('bubble', 4),
   ('thrice', 3),
   ('fire', 3)]},
 {'king': [('shall', 8), ('haue', 7), ('ile', 6), ('macbeth', 5), ('1', 5)]},
 {'mal': [('haue', 10), ('shall', 8), ('would', 6), ('vpon', 5), ('like', 4)]},
 {'cap': [('vpon', 3), ('doe', 2), ('kernes', 2), ('hee', 2), ('till', 2)]},
 {'lenox': [('things', 3),
   ('night', 3),
   ('please', 3),
   ('lord', 3),
   ('haue', 3)]}]`

Comment: @simpleApp how did you get the values to be different??

Comment: i see you have pasted the answer, the result I shared differs from it. 1. replaced `d['macb']` to `d[character]`. got result with `result=[]
names=[e for e in d.keys()]
for each_name in names:
    temp_result=common_words(each_name,filter_stop=True)
    result.append({each_name:temp_result})` let me know for any questions. thx

Comment: @simpleApp That looks phenomenal! Thank you. If you wan to submit it as the answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change 1:** removed static typing from function `common_words`. i.e `d['macb']` to  `d[character]`

```
from collections import Counter
def common_words(character, filter_stop = False, stop_words = []):
    if filter_stop:
        stop_words = set(filter(None, requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sebleier/554280/raw/7e0e4a1ce04c2bb7bd41089c9821dbcf6d0c786c/NLTK's%2520list%2520of%2520english%2520stopwords").text.split('\n')))
    w = [i for _, b in d[character] for i in re.sub('[\:\.\?]+', '', b).split() if i.lower() not in stop_words]
    return Counter(w).most_common(5)
```

**change 2:**  `final_common` can be changed to the following.

```
result=[]
names=[e for e in d.keys()]
for each_name in names:
    temp_result=common_words(each_name,filter_stop=True)
    result.append({each_name:temp_result})
```

output is:

```
[{'all': [('double,', 6),
   ('cauldron', 4),
   ('bubble', 4),
   ('thrice', 3),
   ('fire', 3)]},
 {'king': [('shall', 8), ('haue', 7), ('ile', 6), ('macbeth', 5), ('1', 5)]},
 {'mal': [('haue', 10), ('shall', 8), ('would', 6), ('vpon', 5), ('like', 4)]},
 {'cap': [('vpon', 3), ('doe', 2), ('kernes', 2), ('hee', 2), ('till', 2)]},
 {'lenox': [('things', 3),
   ('night', 3),
   ('please', 3),
   ('lord', 3),
   ('haue', 3)]}]
```

small suggestion: in function `common_words` there is request

```
requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sebleier/554280/raw/7e0e4a1ce04c2bb7bd41089c9821dbcf6d0c786c/NLTK's%2520list%2520of%2520english%2520stopwords"
```

as making the same request multiple times can impact the performance so you can save its response and then consume it subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

### A near–answer

```
chars = [] 

#   -for loop-
# for name in dd:
#     if name[0] not in chars:
#         chars.append(name[0])

# list comprehension does the same as the for loop
[chars.append(name[0]) for name in dd if name not in chars]
        
result = []

for char in chars:
    people = common_words(char)
    if people not in result:
        result += people
result

char_dict = {}

for name in chars:
    if name not in char_dict:
        char_dict[name] = result[:5]
        
char_dict
```

*Close, but this outputs the same values for each key*

```
{'all': [('the', 231), ('and', 156), ('to', 141), ('i', 120), ('of', 119)],
 'king': [('the', 231), ('and', 156), ('to', 141), ('i', 120), ('of', 119)],
 'mal': [('the', 231), ('and', 156), ('to', 141), ('i', 120), ('of', 119)],
 'cap': [('the', 231), ('and', 156), ('to', 141), ('i', 120), ('of', 119)],
 'lenox': [('the', 231), ('and', 156), ('to', 141), ('i', 120), ('of', 119)],
 'rosse': [('the', 231), ('and', 156), ('to', 141), ('i', 120), ('of', 119)], 
...etc
```